# Regex replace - Optional starting @ character

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Currently I'm using `/[^a-z0-9]/i` together with PHP's **preg_replace** to get a new string with all chars which are NOT a-z A-Z 0-9 stripped out, so I'm left with a string containing only a-z A-Z 0-9.

My problem is that I now want the string to be able to contain an **optional @**-char as the **first** char in the string.

Examples:

@aåböc **->** @abc

abcåäö1@23 **->** abc123

How can I make this happen?

Thankful for any help with this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
/([^a-z0-9@]|(?<!^)@)/i
```

Inputs/Outputs:

```
@aåböc      -> @abc
abcåäö1@23  -> abc123
```

[**See demo code here.**](http://ideone.com/yGzhPV)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried your regex with different inputs and it seems to work exactly as I wanted. Now I will finally be able to sleep (5 am), lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace with this regex

```
/(?!^@)[^a-zA-Z\d]+/
```

with

```
empty string
```

[Demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28?!%5E@%29%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5Cd%5D%2b&input=@dfdfdsf%25%5E%5E%25%24cvcvc%0Asdsd@%25%5E%5Ebvvbg)